# Train a custom Mask RCNN with different image sizes in Google Colab. Unfortunately i can't get it running

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

currently I'm trying to train a Matterport Mask R-CNN with custom classes and a custom dataset on Colab. I followed this tutorial:
https://github.com/TannerGilbert/MaskRCNN-Object-Detection-and-Segmentation

Instead of using images with the same size, my images do have different sizes. I spend hours to match the masks(.json) to the image size. But finally it is working:

The following lines are loading two sample images and displaying the segmentation mask:

```
# Load and display random samples
image_ids = np.random.choice(dataset_train.image_ids, 2)
for image_id in image_ids:
    image, img_height, img_width = dataset_train.load_image(image_id)
    mask, class_ids = dataset_train.load_mask(image_id, img_height, img_width)
    visualize.display_top_masks(image, mask, class_ids, dataset_train.class_names)
```

load_image() in utils.py is looking like this:

```
def load_image(self, image_id):
        """Load the specified image and return a [H,W,3] Numpy array.
        """
        # Load image
        image = skimage.io.imread(self.image_info[image_id]['path'])
        img_height, img_width, num_channels = image.shape
        # If grayscale. Convert to RGB for consistency.
        if image.ndim != 3:
            image = skimage.color.gray2rgb(image)
        # If has an alpha channel, remove it for consistency
        if num_channels == 4:
            image = image[..., :3]
        return image, img_height, img_width
```

load_mask() is looking like this:

```
def load_mask(self, image_id, img_height, img_width):
        # get details of image
        info = self.image_info[image_id]
        # define box file location
        path = info['annotation']
        # load XML
        masks, classes = self.extract_masks(path, img_height, img_width)
        return masks, np.asarray(classes, dtype='int32')
```

And extract_mask() is looking like this:

```
def extract_masks(self, filename, img_height, img_width):
        json_file = os.path.join(filename)
        with open(json_file) as f:
            img_anns = json.load(f)
            
        masks = np.zeros([img_height, img_width, len(img_anns['shapes'])], dtype='uint8')
        classes = []
        for i, anno in enumerate(img_anns['shapes']):
            mask = np.zeros([img_height, img_width], dtype=np.uint8)
            cv2.fillPoly(mask, np.array([anno['points']], dtype=np.int32), 1)
            masks[:, :, i] = mask
            classes.append(self.class_names.index(anno['label']))
        return masks, classes
```

Now we are getting to the curious part...

After going on with my code creating the model

```
# Create model in training mode
model = modellib.MaskRCNN(mode="training", config=config,
                          model_dir=MODEL_DIR)
```

...and choosing the weights to start with

```
# Which weights to start with?
init_with = "coco"  # imagenet, coco, or last

if init_with == "imagenet":
    model.load_weights(model.get_imagenet_weights(), by_name=True)
elif init_with == "coco":
    # Load weights trained on MS COCO, but skip layers that
    # are different due to the different number of classes
    # See README for instructions to download the COCO weights
    model.load_weights(COCO_MODEL_PATH, by_name=True,
                       exclude=["mrcnn_class_logits", "mrcnn_bbox_fc", 
                                "mrcnn_bbox", "mrcnn_mask"])
elif init_with == "last":
    # Load the last model you trained and continue training
    model.load_weights(model.find_last(), by_name=True)
```

...I get to the point where training should start:

```
model.train(dataset_train, dataset_val, 
            learning_rate=config.LEARNING_RATE, 
            epochs=5, 
            layers='heads')
```

I'm receiving following error:

```
/content/drive/My Drive/Colab/Mask_RCNN/mrcnn/model.py in load_image_gt()
   1210     # Load image and mask
   1211     image, img_height, img_width = dataset.load_image(image_id)
-> 1212     mask, class_ids = dataset.load_mask(image_id, img_height, img_width)
   1213     original_shape = image.shape
   1214     image, window, scale, padding, crop = utils.resize_image(

TypeError: load_mask() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'img_height' and 'img_width'
```

I noticed, that load_image_gt() is different to the above mentioned load_image(). I've already adjusted load_image_gt() as followed (I added  **#<-------** to the relevant lines):

```
def load_image_gt(dataset, config, image_id, augment=False, augmentation=None,
                  use_mini_mask=False):
    """Load and return ground truth data for an image (image, mask, bounding boxes).

    augment: (deprecated. Use augmentation instead). If true, apply random
        image augmentation. Currently, only horizontal flipping is offered.
    augmentation: Optional. An imgaug (https://github.com/aleju/imgaug) augmentation.
        For example, passing imgaug.augmenters.Fliplr(0.5) flips images
        right/left 50% of the time.
    use_mini_mask: If False, returns full-size masks that are the same height
        and width as the original image. These can be big, for example
        1024x1024x100 (for 100 instances). Mini masks are smaller, typically,
        224x224 and are generated by extracting the bounding box of the
        object and resizing it to MINI_MASK_SHAPE.

    Returns:
    image: [height, width, 3]
    shape: the original shape of the image before resizing and cropping.
    class_ids: [instance_count] Integer class IDs
    bbox: [instance_count, (y1, x1, y2, x2)]
    mask: [height, width, instance_count]. The height and width are those
        of the image unless use_mini_mask is True, in which case they are
        defined in MINI_MASK_SHAPE.
    """
    # Load image and mask
    image, img_height, img_width = dataset.load_image(image_id)                    **#<-------**
    mask, class_ids = dataset.load_mask(image_id, img_height, img_width)           **#<-------** 
    original_shape = image.shape
    image, window, scale, padding, crop = utils.resize_image(
        image,
        min_dim=config.IMAGE_MIN_DIM,
        min_scale=config.IMAGE_MIN_SCALE,
        max_dim=config.IMAGE_MAX_DIM,
        mode=config.IMAGE_RESIZE_MODE)
    mask = utils.resize_mask(mask, scale, padding, crop)

    # Random horizontal flips.
    # TODO: will be removed in a future update in favor of augmentation
    if augment:
        logging.warning("'augment' is deprecated. Use 'augmentation' instead.")
        if random.randint(0, 1):
            image = np.fliplr(image)
            mask = np.fliplr(mask)

    # Augmentation
    # This requires the imgaug lib (https://github.com/aleju/imgaug)
    if augmentation:
        import imgaug

        # Augmenters that are safe to apply to masks
        # Some, such as Affine, have settings that make them unsafe, so always
        # test your augmentation on masks
        MASK_AUGMENTERS = ["Sequential", "SomeOf", "OneOf", "Sometimes",
                           "Fliplr", "Flipud", "CropAndPad",
                           "Affine", "PiecewiseAffine"]

        def hook(images, augmenter, parents, default):
            """Determines which augmenters to apply to masks."""
            return augmenter.__class__.__name__ in MASK_AUGMENTERS

        # Store shapes before augmentation to compare
        image_shape = image.shape
        mask_shape = mask.shape
        # Make augmenters deterministic to apply similarly to images and masks
        det = augmentation.to_deterministic()
        image = det.augment_image(image)
        # Change mask to np.uint8 because imgaug doesn't support np.bool
        mask = det.augment_image(mask.astype(np.uint8),
                                 hooks=imgaug.HooksImages(activator=hook))
        # Verify that shapes didn't change
        assert image.shape == image_shape, "Augmentation shouldn't change image size"
        assert mask.shape == mask_shape, "Augmentation shouldn't change mask size"
        # Change mask back to bool
        mask = mask.astype(np.bool)

    # Note that some boxes might be all zeros if the corresponding mask got cropped out.
    # and here is to filter them out
    _idx = np.sum(mask, axis=(0, 1)) > 0
    mask = mask[:, :, _idx]
    class_ids = class_ids[_idx]
    # Bounding boxes. Note that some boxes might be all zeros
    # if the corresponding mask got cropped out.
    # bbox: [num_instances, (y1, x1, y2, x2)]
    bbox = utils.extract_bboxes(mask)

    # Active classes
    # Different datasets have different classes, so track the
    # classes supported in the dataset of this image.
    active_class_ids = np.zeros([dataset.num_classes], dtype=np.int32)
    source_class_ids = dataset.source_class_ids[dataset.image_info[image_id]["source"]]
    active_class_ids[source_class_ids] = 1

    # Resize masks to smaller size to reduce memory usage
    if use_mini_mask:
        mask = utils.minimize_mask(bbox, mask, config.MINI_MASK_SHAPE)

    # Image meta data
    image_meta = compose_image_meta(image_id, original_shape, image.shape,
                                    window, scale, active_class_ids)

    return image, img_height, img_width, image_meta, class_ids, bbox, mask          **#<-------**
```

I don't know why the two requied arguments are missing, because img_height and img_with are defined, arent't they?
In my oppion the code is exactly the same like the "# Load and display random samples"-code mentioned above.

I would be very gratefull, if someone could help.
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You must set width and height value in `load_yourdatasetname()` by `self.add_imge` and get in `load_mask` function

Example:

```
class Covid19Dataset(utils.Dataset):

    def load_covid19(self, dataset_dir, subset):
        """Load a subset of the covid-19 dataset.
        dataset_dir: Root directory of the dataset.
        subset: Subset to load: train or val
        """
        # Add classes. We have three class to add.
        self.add_class("covid19", 1, "lung right")
        self.add_class("covid19", 2, "lung left")
        self.add_class("covid19", 3, "infection")

        # Train or validation dataset?
        assert subset in ["train", "val"]
        dataset_dir = os.path.join(dataset_dir, subset)
        dataset_Image_dir =  os.path.join(dataset_dir, "Images")
        dataset_Labels_dir =  os.path.join(dataset_dir, "Labels")

        # get image names in dataset directory
        filenamesInDir = [f for f in listdir(dataset_Image_dir) if isfile(join(dataset_Image_dir, f))]
        png_filenames = []
        for name in filenamesInDir:
          # Skip if file does not end with .png
          if not name.endswith(".png") : continue
          png_filenames.append(name)

        # Add images
        for a in png_filenames:

            image_path = os.path.join(dataset_Image_dir, a)
            label_path = os.path.join(dataset_Labels_dir, a)
            image = skimage.io.imread(image_path)
            height, width = image.shape[:2]

            self.add_image(
                "covid19",
                image_id=a,  # use file name as a unique image id
                path=image_path,
                label_path=label_path,
                width=width, height=height)

    def load_mask(self, image_id):
        """Generate instance masks for an image.
       Returns:
        masks: A bool array of shape [height, width, instance count] with
            one mask per instance.
        class_ids: a 1D array of class IDs of the instance masks.
        """
        # If not a covid19 dataset image, delegate to parent class.
        image_info = self.image_info[image_id]
        if image_info["source"] != "covid19":
            return super(self.__class__, self).load_mask(image_id)

        # [height, width, instance_count]
        info = self.image_info[image_id]
        label = skimage.io.imread(info["label_path"])
        Class_names = np.unique(label)
        Class_names = Class_names[1:]
        mask = np.zeros([info["height"], info["width"], len(Class_names)],
                        dtype=np.uint8)
        class_ids = []
        for i,p in enumerate(Class_names):
          mask[label==p,i]=1
          class_ids.append(i+1)
        # Return mask, and array of class IDs of each instance. Since we have
        class_ids = np.array(class_ids, dtype=np.int32)
        mask = np.rot90(mask)
        return mask.astype(np.bool), class_ids

    def image_reference(self, image_id):
        """Return the path of the image."""
        info = self.image_info[image_id]
        if info["source"] == "covid19":
            return info["path"]
        else:
            super(self.__class__, self).image_reference(image_id)

    def load_image(self, image_id):
        """Load the specified image and return a [H,W,3] Numpy array.
        """
        # Load image
        image = skimage.io.imread(self.image_info[image_id]['path'])

        #image = rotate(image, 90, resize=False)
        image = np.rot90(image)

        # If grayscale. Convert to RGB for consistency.
        if image.ndim != 3:
            image = skimage.color.gray2rgb(image)
        # If has an alpha channel, remove it for consistency
        if image.shape[-1] == 4:
            image = image[..., :3]
        return image
```